# django-jenkins - not generating any coverage.xml report for django -restframework

Tags: python, django, jenkins, coverage.py, django-jenkins

I am trying to integrate django-jenkins in my django-rest framework application.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (.....
                      ......
                      'django_jenkins',
                      .......
                     )
```

For running test-case with coverage, I have tired below command as per documentation.

```
 python manage.py jenkins  --enable-coverage
```

I am able to successfully run my test cases without any exception.

But in reports directory. I could see only one junit.xml file  and the coverage reports (coverage.xml) are not generated.

Need help to resolve this issue, whether i am missing any another configurations.

Thanks

Comment: So, what is command output? Does it have line like "Storing coverage info..."?

Comment: I am getting the output same as while run coverage with coverage run  manage.py test -  I cant find any storing coverage info.. message. @kmmbvnr

Comment: Please add full output of `manage.py jenkins  --enable-coverage` in the question